# Need to accept the privacy policy before I can access a page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape information from AllRecipes.co.uk however when the code is run, I am not directed to the intended page, instead to a covering which asks me to accept the privacy policy beforehand. This means I cannot scrape from the page I want since any page that I access comes with this Accept Privacy Policy cover

Website is AllRecipes.co.uk

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import numpy as np
import os


userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
headers = {
        'user-agent': userAgent
    }

dishType = "main-recipes"
url = 'http://allrecipes.co.uk/recipes/' + dishType + '.aspx?page='
#endPage = 1259
endPage = 3
for i in range(2, endPage):
    delays = [5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
    delay = np.random.choice(delays)
    time.sleep(delay)
    print("Getting request " + str(i))
    r = requests.get(url + str(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup)
    #names = soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class' : "col-sm-7"})
    #for name in names:
    #    print(name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the `euConsentId` cookie:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: url = "http://allrecipes.co.uk/recipes/main-recipes.aspx?page=2"

In [4]: BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser").title.get_text()
Out[4]: 'About your privacy on this site'

In [5]: import uuid

In [6]: BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, cookies={'euConsentId': str(uuid.uuid4())}).content, "html.parser").title.get_text()
Out[6]: 'Main course recipes - All recipes UK '
```

---

In order to adapt that in your code, I'd instantiate a ["session"](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and set the cookie there:

```
import uuid4

consent_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.cookies = {'euConsentId': consent_id}

    response = session.get(...)
```